# Converting CSV data to list in dictionary

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a CSV file in the following form:

```
Name_1,2,K,14
Name_1,3,T,14
Name_1,4,T,18
Name_2,2,G,12
Name_2,4,T,14
Name_2,6,K,15
Name_3,2,K,12
Name_3,3,T,15
Name_3,4,G,18
```

And I want to convert it into a dictionary where `Name_x` is the key and corresponding data is the value in list form. Something like this:

```
{'Name_1': [[2, 'K', 14], [3, 'T', 14], [4, 'T', 18]],
 'Name_2': [[4, 'T', 14], [4, 'T', 14], [6, 'K' ,15]],
...}
```

So far, I think I have to use use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
```

But how do I `append` the data to `d`? I know `defaultdict` does not have an `append` method.

Comment: `d[key].append(new_val)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the name as the key and append the slice of the row as the value, there will be no order using a normal or defaultdict:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('in.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for row in r:
        d[row[0]].append(row[1:])
print(d)
```

If you want to maintain order you will need an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('in.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = OrderedDict()
    for row in r:
        # get key/ first element in row
        key = row[0]
        # create key/list paring if it does not exist, else just append the value
        od.setdefault(key, []).append(row[1:])
print(od)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Name_1', [['2', 'K', '14'], ['3', 'T', '14'], ['4', 'T', '18']]), ('Name_2', [['2', 'G', '12'], ['4', 'T', '14'], ['6', 'K', '15']]), ('Name_3', [['2', 'K', '12'], ['3', 'T', '15'], ['4', 'G', '18']])])
```

You could also use groupby if the names are grouped which will group elements based on the first item/name in each row:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('in.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in groupby(r, key=itemgetter(0)):
        od[k] = [sub[1:] for sub in v]
```

If you are using python3 you can unpack using `*`:

```
with open("in.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = OrderedDict()
    for row in r:
        key, *rest = row
        od.setdefault(key, []).append(rest)


import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('in.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in groupby(r, key=itemgetter(0)):
        od[k] = [sub for _, *sub in v]
print(od)
```

Comment: Minor improvement: key = row.pop(0) and then od.setdefault(key, []).append(row)

Comment: This works, thank you! Nice of you to add the OrderedDict possiblity as well - that is exactly what I want.
Is it actually possible to acces the values by index?
So e.g. `Name_1[1]` would give me `'K','T','T'`. I can access a single letter by `["Name_1"][1][1]`, but I need all the letters (in the same order).

Comment: @Hjalte, sure just  `print(list(zip(*od["Name_1"]))[1])`,  that will transpose the sublists or `print([sub[1] for sub in od["Name_1"]])`

Comment: @simleo, can you explain to me, why this is an improvement? (I'm a Python newbie).

Comment: @Hjalte because row[1:] makes a copy of almost the entire list. Since your're going to throw it away, you can just pop out the first element so that what remains is the sublist you need to build the dict

Answer (score 0):

```
txtcsv="""Name_1,2,K,14
Name_1,3,T,14
Name_1,4,T,18
Name_2,2,G,12
Name_2,4,T,14
Name_2,6,K,15
Name_3,2,K,12
Name_3,3,T,15
Name_3,4,G,18"""

def save():
    with open("test.csv","w") as f:
        f.write(txtcsv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    save()
    with open("test.csv") as f:
        d = {}
        for l in f.readlines():
            name, val = l.rstrip().split(",", 1)
            d.setdefault(name, []).append(val.split(","))
        print (d)
```

Comment: not my downvote but there is no need to read all the lines into memory, with closes your files automatically so the  f.close() is redundant.  You can also use rstrip to remove from the end of the string and use dict.setdefault to handle repeating keys..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham of course for close ! That's right, stripping both sides is unusefull! I'm not used to use setdefault but it's indeed better. Thank you!

Comment: I downvoted it since you don't use the `csv` library. This is clearly a situation where you should use it. I bet there is multiple things that could go wrong, but on the top of my head; what if a name contains a comma? Remember, Python has batteries included.

Comment: @SteinarLima note that it was never mentioned that the code has to be working with any CSV, even if the title can suggest it, the question concerns a particular file with a provided format. So this code answers the posted question. Next time SteinarLima please don't downvote without explanation (unusefull) and consider also the response regarding to the asked question.

Comment: Erm, you don't know what `Name_1` is, and what if it changes tomorrow? Not using the `csv` lib when you have it included in Python is just stupid. On top of this, you don't use `defaultdict`, which is clearly perfectly suited for this problem, and was specifically mentioned in the question.  And if you choose _not_ to use it, please don't set the default   value on each iteration.

Comment: When it comes to downvoting and not commenting - I don't have time to comment on every downvote I give, but I try to check back on my downvotes and see if any furter explanation is required.

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head (because I'm not too familiar with defaultdict), this should do roughly what you want.

data is the CSV string

```
obj = {}

data = data.split('\n')
for row in data:
    row = row.split(',')
    if row[0] in obj:
        obj[row[0]].append(row[1:])
    else:
        obj[row[0]] = [row[1:]]

print obj
```

Comment: Curious as to why the -1?